# typeof() when Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'string'

Tags: c#, typeof

I'm doing some Xml Serialization, and I'm getting a compile item error.

The code with the error is:

```
public class EPubBody
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Image", DataType = typeof(EPubImage))]
    public object[] BodyItems;
}
```

The error is on the `typeof(EPubImage)` part.  The error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'string'`.

The class `EPubImage` is in the same namspace, and looks like this:

```
public class EPubImage
{
    [XmlAttribute("imagePath")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

}
```

I guess `typeof(EPubImage)` is returning a `System.Type` instead of an `string`.  Any pointers on how to ensure that the typeof statement will return a string, instead of a System.Type?

Comment: Possibly `typeof(EPubImage).ToString()`

Comment: `DataType` is most likely expecting a string, not a type.  Try using the fully qualified name of `EPubImage`.

Comment: @Tim I though when it says it's expect a `string` it meant it wanted a 32 bit integer. I must be wrong then.

Comment: @Tim can't take a joke?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Sure, I can take a joke; when it's clear it's a joke. I figured you were making a humorous comment, but I wasn't 100% sure, hence my "huh" :)

Comment: @Tim I was thinking about adding a You don't say image link, but I didn't bother :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN Documentation for XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype.aspx) clearly states that `DataType` is `string`, whereas the `Type` property is of `Type`.

Comment: I guess I was misled by the example in the Remarks of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Are there any overrides I can do so that typeof(EPubImage) will return a string?

Comment: No.. what you need in an attribute is a _compile-time constant_. That is not what an operator/function that returns a `string` provides. The simple fact that it _returns_ anything means it can be variable (since C# doesn't have the concept of _constness_).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype.aspx), the `DataType` property is used to specify an XSD data type, not a .NET type:

> An XML Schema data type, as defined by the World Wide Web Consortium (www.w3.org) document named "XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes".

Try this instead:

```
public class EPubBody
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Image")]
    public EPubImage[] BodyItems;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the field an an array of object, since I will be using multiple types, as per the samples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found an override for XmlElement() for XmlElement(string, Type), so I tried this instead, and it works.

```
public class EPubBody
{
    [XmlElement("image", typeof(EPubImage))]
    public object[] BodyItems;
}
```

When I say "it works", I mean I no longer the the compile time error.  Having it exhibit the behaviour as seen in the [Remarks section of this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), is another issue.